# Show $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on the interval $[0,2]$ which is differentiable at all points except $1$.Also $\lim f^{'}(x)=5$ .Show $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$.

**My effort**:

Consider $h\neq 0$ very small.Then $f$ is differentiable at $1+h$.

By definition of derivative $f^{'}(1+h)=\lim _{h_1\to 0}\dfrac{f(1+h+h_1)-f(1+h)}{h_1}\rightarrow (1)$

Also $\lim _{x\to 1}f^{'}(x)=5\implies \lim_{h\to 0}f^{'}(1+h)=5\rightarrow (2)$

Now putting $(2)$ in $(1)$ we have $\lim_{h\to 0}\lim _{h_1\to 0}\dfrac{f(1+h+h_1)-f(1+h)}{h_1}=5$

$\hspace{45mm}\implies $$\lim_{h_1\to 0}\lim _{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(1+h+h_1)-f(1+h)}{h_1}=5$

As $f$ is continuous ;$\lim_{h_1\to 0}\dfrac{f(1+h_1)-f(1)}{h_1}=5$

Similarly we have $\lim_{h_1\to 0}\dfrac{f(1)-f(1-h_1)}{h_1}=5$

Thus $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$

Is it right?Please check and suggest required edits

Comment: You said that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=1$, how can you prove a statement that contradict the assumptions of the exercise?

Comment: You swap limits in your argument. Are you sure that is allowed? Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{x^2+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1$ and $\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^3}{y^2}=0$

Comment: By $\lim f'(x)=5$ do you mean $lim_{x\to 1}f'(x)=5$?

Comment: What do you mean with "$\,\lim f'(x)=5\,$" ? The limit *where* ?

Comment: I believe he means "differentiable at all points except possibly at 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said @Hagen von Eitzen in the comments above, swapping limits is not allowed in general. To avoid this, you may use Mean Value Theorem as follows.

We want to show that $f$ is diferentiable at 1, i.e. that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$$
exists and is finite. 
Now, MVT applied on $[1,1+h]$ gives the existence of a $c_h\in(1,1+h)$ s.t.
$$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=f'(c_h)$$
Now, since $1<c_h<1+h$, we obtain that $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} c_h=1$ and hence
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0} f'(c_h)=\lim_{x\to 1} f'(x) =5$$ : QED.

Answer (score 1):

Use MVT.

$f(1+h)-f(1) = hf'(c)$ for some $c \in (1,1+h)$. Then $\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} = f'(c)$ and taking limits, $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} = \lim_{c \to 1} f'(c) = 5$. The existence of the limit of the derivative makes the argument work.